# first JS, looking for advice from experienced JS programmer

Tags: javascript

I need to write a script to show particular divs on particular dates. My pseudocode looks like this so far:

```
import date from local system, //not sure if can/should do this?
var date == dateImported

switch(date){
    case date less than or equal to feb 14th:
          div called .valentines{ display: block;}
    break;
    case date equal to or less than march 17th:
          div called .paddys{display: block}
    break;
    case date between last event and dec 25th:
        div called .christmas display: block;
    break;
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a cleaner way to do this?
2. Whats the best way to decide the date variables value in this script?
3. How should I make sure the `div` is hidden again after each occasion has passed?

I'm thinking I should I try not to be so specific and just use:
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
and have a `div` for each month instead but I'd like to aim higher than that

Please don't write the code up for me, I want the practice. I just want guidance, much appreciated.

Comment: It's indeed possible. But not with `switch - case`. You need to use `if`. You can get the current date from `var date = new Date()`.

Comment: georg has provided a good answer.  As an alternative, you can also do this on the server side. See this [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/) example: [Display content based on date with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493167/display-content-based-on-date-with-php).

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this would be the following:

Add two attributes to the divs in question like `data-display-after` and `data-display-before`, for example:

```
<div id="valentines" 
    data-display-after="2016-02-14 00:00:00" 
    data-display-before="2016-02-15 00:00:00">...
```

Hide these divs initially (with CSS).

On page load, convert the current date (`new Date`) into the above format.

For each element in document that has the `data-display-before` attribute (you'll need `querySelectorAll`), compare attribute values (`getAttribute`) and if `currentDate >= data-display-after && currentDate <= data-display-after`, then show the element.

This way, your JS and your markup will be "decoupled" and easy to maintain.

Comment: Hi Georg, fantastic answer, thank you. do you mind if I ask you: do you think I can use the data display after part above with only the day of month and month values so that the same script works next year and again without needing update?

Comment: Sure, just remember to use the same format when converting the Date object.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm set

Answer (score 1):

I would use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to check dates.

```
var today = moment();
today.isBetween('2014-1-1', '2017-1-1'); // true
today.isBetween('2001-1-1', '2010-1-1'); // false
```

With moment, you can query before, same, after, combos of both, etc.

With that, you can use switches and add/remove classes to hide/show divs base on those switches with a javascript library (i.e. jquery).